# Use R to Create Slideshow with Timed Transition

Tags: r

Is there a way to create an timed autoplay (like PowerPoint) with revealjs? I'm not seeing any way to create timed transitions (which don't require user interaction to toggle to the next slide). I considered Shiny as well, but didn't find a way to do this. Perhaps there is a way to render a PowerPoint with the play/transition settings already configured?

Comment: Not sure about reveal, but I did this with Xaringan. Beyond that, it would be much better if you made a [mcve], since just asking for tool recommendations is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Shiny may work if you used [shinyjs::delay](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/overview).

Description: Execute R code (including any shinyjs functions) after a specified amount of time.